# IO Exception in .NET Core application

Tags: windows, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am just starting working with ASP.NET Core 2.0 on a Windows machine. I cannot run kestrel server due to the port 5000 being used by some other apps.

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.IO.IOException An unhandled exception of
>       type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'Failed to
>       bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.'

The issue is that I kill the process and run the `dotnet run` command. It works but for the second time I get the error again. So somehow I should the port should be released when I stop debugging but it doesn't. Any tips?

Comment: Just use a different port.

Comment: the issue is which everytime I run dotnet run command I get this issue even after killing the process

Comment: If you get that error the *second* time it means your application is still running and using that port. How did you terminate it? What happens if you enter `http://127.0.0.1:5000` in your browser? I suspect you'll get back a response from the app

Comment: You can use `netstat -a -b` or [TcpView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to see which application keeps that port open.

Comment: It is important to record what you did so as to find out what are the steps to reproduce the issue. Then you can figure out what exactly leaves a Kestrel process at port 5000. As the rule is simple that you can only run a single Kestrel on that port, you can revise your usual workflow to avoid duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands in an admin command prompt:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

It will restart the service that "network address Translation". The service reserves ports dynamically and once in a while it will reserve ports that collide with your application. The commands solve the problem for me most of the times, no need to change port.

Sources:

[How to see what is reserving ephemeral port ranges on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010365/how-to-see-what-is-reserving-ephemeral-port-ranges-on-windows)
https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2001

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same. Here is the solution please refer to this:-

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3110

change your port in the program.cs and launch setting.json file.

eg  - :  webBuilder.UseUrls("http://localhost:6980");

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and based on the karnveer0098 answer, I just changed the line "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60758" inside of 'launchSettings.json', to another port number, then all came back to normal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked. I only needed to restart the PC.