# GRPC Init throws "IOException: Failed to bind port " when running from .netcore app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, grpc

I have a .net core app which spins up a grpc server. I was able to run it locally without a problem until I had Windows updates today. After Windows applied latest updates, I tried to run my .net core app, but I keep getting the following error.

> System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind port "127.0.0.1:50001"
>      at Grpc.Core.Server.CheckPortsBoundSuccessfully()

I went to firewall and opened access to the port that grpc has problem accessing. It did not help. Anybody had this issue?

Comment: which port is it trying to bind to? is something else using it?

Comment: I checked it is not being used. It is 50000 range

Comment: This really looks like someone's using that port. Have you tried a different port? There isn't much complexity in binding the code that binds the port on the server side - it mostly just invokes the syscall to bind the port (and that seems to be failing).  Can other servers (non-grpc) bind that port without a problem?

Comment: @neo Did you find a resolution to this? I'm having the exact same issue now on code that's been working fine for over a year. Port is NOT in use.

Comment: @user3953989 I posted the answer.

Comment: @neo Thanks for the follow up and link! I came to this same conclusion but couldn't find any documentation to prove it.

Answer (score 7):

I wasted 2 days on this and finally got the answer. Windows update caused certain valid to use ports to be excluded and as a result I couldn't run any app that listens on those excluded ports.

Here is a link to Microsoft article. [Windows update blocking previously valid ports](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093046/ports-blocked-after-you-install-monthly-rollup-package-kb4074588)

Comment: Your answer reminded of the right search, but the link is dead. Consider changing it to something like

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010365/how-to-see-what-is-reserving-ephemeral-port-ranges-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can change the startup project to current selection by right click on your solution. or you can set multiple starup project as shown in pictur. it solve my issue..
[image: step1]

step 2
[image: step 2]

[image: click apply]