# "The specified port is in use" IIS Express error when debugging specific project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I have been using this same project for years without having this issue. Suddenly it happens every time I first boot my PC.

If I go into the log, this is the error I get:

```
Failed to register URL "http://localhost:50496/" for site "FMSProd(1)" application "/". Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x80070020)
```

Running command prompt as administrator and running "net stop winnat" followed by "net start winnat" fixes the issue until the next boot. But I have to do it every time I reboot.

I have traced the process using that port, it's devenv(visual studio). Version of visual studio does not matter. Changing the port number on the project does not fix it.

Is there anything I can do to fix this and prevent it from recurring every single reboot?

Comment: I wonder if doing a `netsh <...> add excludedportrange <...>` would solve this? some related-sounding threads/blogs mention it. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010365/), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1469431/), [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1103107/). I have no idea what I'm talking about though, so maybe these make it worse :P